# How to send a canvas element in binary to a server in dart

Tags: canvas, base64, dart

How do I send a canvas element to a server using Dart without the overhead of base64 encryption?

Answer (score 4):

This code converts a canvas element to a binary format in dart:

```dart
import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:core';
import 'dart:typed_data';

/*** possible values for imagetype: 'image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/webp' 
 *** see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement
 ***/
Uint8List toUploadData(CanvasElement canvas, String imagetype, num quality) =>
  new Uint8List.fromList(window.atob(canvas.toDataUrl(imagetype,
      quality).split(",")[1]).codeUnits);
```

It can then be uploaded as follows:

```dart
UploadImageData(Uint8List imagedata) =>
    HttpRequest.request('myserverscript.php',
        method:"POST",
        sendData: imagedata);
```